# What is the typical usage of x509 certificates with security tokens?

Tags: .net, security, x509certificate, wif

I am wondering how to use x509 certificates with WIF security tokens. Could you please provide a typical scenario? For example, I want to sign and encrypt a security token with a certificate/certificates. How could I do that? What benefits would I get? In what way should I deploy certificates on productive environment?

Comment: Have a look at this,
http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/04/09/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question: "how do I do that" has has no other concise answer than "with WIF API". The API plays nicely with X509 certificates so that both encryption and signing just require X509Certificate2 class instances (in other words: certificates).

Another question: what are benefits? Well, token signing is fundamental way of enforcing the protocol. If a SAML token is not signed, there is no way of validating if it really comes from the token service. On the other hand, encryption is optional and if the same token can safely be delivered to different applications then there is probably no need to encrypt tokens. If different tokens are delivered to different applications (for example, a user can be in administrator role in siteA and not in siteB and the token service delivers different tokens for A and B) then encryption prevents user from misusing tokens.

The last question: how do I deploy certificates? Well, it is up to you. There are tons of possibilities as the X509Certificate2 class is flexible and allows you to pass byte array as the parameter. You can then load certificates from files, from web services, from embedded resources. In practice, however, the most convenient way is to use one of system certificate stores, for example the My store of the LocalMachine. First you use the mmc snapin to import certificates into the store, then you give permissions to access the private key to certain users (application pools for example) and then your code just load certificates from the store.